# want to know maximum size of datatype like lookup(User),lookup(Account),Date,Checkbox,standard id field,Formula(TEXT)

Tags: formula-field, lookup, fields

I want to know maximum size of datatype like

> lookup(User),lookup(Account),Date,Checkbox,standard id field,Formula(TEXT)

I am preparing a data model. I have to integrate with sql database for I need these details.

Comment: Lookup, date  and checkbox- how can you have size in them?

Comment: Like for lookup(user) it can be of 200 characters like first name(40 chars)+middle name(40 chars)+last name(80 chars)+ suffix name(40 chars) so like that i want to know size of other field.This i have found using google.